# Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110] in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, gmail, laravel-5

I am trying to send an gmail with laravel 5.2. But it is throwing this error

> Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 269: Connection
>   could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed
>   out #110]

*it work fine in localhost* 
this my **.env** file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=my@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

and this my **mail.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill",
    |            "ses", "sparkpost", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => ['address' => '', 'name' => ''],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' =>env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

];
```

Comment: are you using plain password eg `123@stack&` or some hashed password eg `Gh78$35#4....` also tell me that, is 2 way authentication is switched on for your gmail account ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: Either you must allow less secure apps or use app password by enabling 2 step verification on your gmail acc.

2: Disable any antivirus on your machine(this is something no one will tell u but is necessary in many cases).

3: Don't forget to clear your cache (sometimes it don't take updated content from .env file)

4: You don't need to change anything in Mailer inside config directory(not recommended), you should use env variables

Comment: Disabling temporarily av did it for me, everything were in order.

Answer (score 2):

Try change the port number to `587`.

in mail.php

```
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
```

in .env

```
MAIL_PORT=465
```

Answer (score -2):

Just disable antivirus from your machine